# How can I get WorkbookPart from WorkSheet?

Tags: excel, openxml

I am trying to create Excel file using OpenXML SDK. I have one situation to get WorkBookPart from WorkSheet instance. How can I get it?
Thanks.
Ant.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would give the full RIGHT answer of what Ant was asking.  I came across this question when I was searching for the same answer. This is tested and works.

Lets say for some reason you have a Worksheet object named worksheet:

```
Worksheet worksheet = ((WorksheetPart)_spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartById("rId1")).Worksheet;
```

Now maybe, later on in my program I need to get the Workbook Part for some reason:

```
WorkbookPart workbookPart = (WorkbookPart) worksheet.WorksheetPart.GetParentParts().First();
```

That's all!

Answer (score 3):

```
worksheet.WorksheetPart.GetParentParts().First()
```

This should get the `WorkBookPart`, where worksheet is the `WorkSheet` instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a path from Worksheet to Workbook through the Package object:

```
Worksheet ws = someWorksheet;
SpreadsheetDocument ssDoc = ws.WorksheetPart.OpenXmlPackage as SpreadsheetDocument;
Workbook = ssDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which property are you looking for?

You can find the list of the properties on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507946.aspx), especially, you can find the `Workbook` property, for instance, you would use `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook`